# Async, React, асинхронизация функций React

Tags: reactjs, асинхронность

Есть код:

```
  areasGet = async(Index) => {
    let res = await fetch(`https://api.hh.ru/areas/113`)
    let json = await res.json()
    this.setState({
      areaData: json,
      isLoadArea: true
    })
     // console.log(json)
  }

  specGet = async(Index) => {
    let res = await fetch(`https://api.hh.ru/specializations`)
    let json = await res.json()
    this.setState({
      specData: json,
      isLoadSpec: true
    })
  }

  industriesGet = async(Index) => {
    let res = await fetch(`https://api.hh.ru/industries`)
    let json = await res.json()
    this.setState({
      industriesData: json,
      isLoadInd: true
    })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.areasGet()
    this.specGet()
    this.industriesGet()
  }
```

При выполнении, то одно не заполнилось, то другое, рандом вообщем. Вроде синхроны, но почему ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы использовать `async/await` вам необходимо сделать метод `componentDidMount` асинхронным:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.areasGet();
    await this.specGet();
    await this.industriesGet();
  }
```

либо с помощью стрелочной функции вида:

```
  componentDidMount = async () => {
    await this.areasGet();
    await this.specGet();
    await this.industriesGet();
  };
```

Подробнее про `async/await` можно почитать [тут](https://javascript.info/async-await).

Comment: Спасибо) Я думал достаточно сами функции async объявить)